# Difference between @"pack://application:,,,[...] and IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've noticed that when I add a line of `<Window.Background></Window.Background>` in the XAML file or in the C# code `this.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new uri([...]));` if I put in the "Uri" this: `new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Myapp;component/image.jpg")` I get an error when I try to compile it which says: "Could not locate resource "image.jpg" "

But if I change this to `new Uri(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+"\\image.jpg");` it never gives me an error. Why???? What is the difference between both methods? I am very comfortable with `Directory` but why the compiler doesn't show an error "Locating" the resource with `IO.Directory`? What's the difference?

The questions may sound too noob, but I don't understand why it gives an error in `@"pack://application[...]` and not with `GetCurrentDirectory()`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Ohh sorry, thanks @JohnSaunders ^^

Answer (score 2):

A `pack://` Uri, will search embedded resources for the image. The resources are *inside* the DLL/EXE, rather than deployed to the same folder. To use an image as a WPF Resource you need to set the `Build Action` on the image to `Resource`.

Using the `Directory` approach simply searches the physical file system for the image.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on WPF Pack Uri's.

Comment: Ohhh o:
Interesting ~ Thanks :3